# make:entity symfony command gives error in doctrineHelper.php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, composer-php

I'm trying to make an entity User using the command line `php bin/console make:entity`

But it keeps giving me this error:

```
In DoctrineHelper.php line 187:

  Cannot access protected property Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::$classNames


make:entity [-a|--api-resource] [-b|--broadcast] [--regenerate] [--overwrite] [--] [<name>]
```

I have followed the official website instructions to download all the requirements https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/doctrine.html

`composer.json`:

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.4",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.17|^2",
        "symfony/form": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/process": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/string": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/webapp-meta": "^1.0",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.12",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.38",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.4.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in your composer.json?  Have you attempted to run php `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: @gview please check my edit i have run the command u suggested and still nothing

Comment: Symfony 6 affected too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was triggered by the newly released Doctrine ORM 2.12.0

Until a fix is pushed, either by Symfony or Doctrine (haven't had time yet to check which package is "at fault"), you can downgrade to Doctrine ORM 2.11.3.

In your `composer.json` change the line:

```
 "doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
```

to:

```
 "doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
```

And modify your `conflict` section so that 2.12 does not get installed:

```
"conflict": {
      "symfony/symfony": "*",
      "doctrine/orm": "2.12.0"
    },
```

After this, run `composer update doctrine/orm` to downgrade the package, and `bin/console make:entity` should work again.

---

I see that the issue [has been reported to symfony/maker-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1090) some days ago. Monitoring this issue would be a good way to know when you can upgrade the Maker bundle and remove the `doctrine/orm` conflict declaration from your configuration.